# Android - How to set TextInputEditText dynamically while incrementing the hint and adding a scroll view?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm trying to get my button to create a new TextInputEditText field every time the user presses the button. So far I've managed to dynamically add a field but I can't figure out how to increment the hint of the EditText.

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.holder);
            TextInputEditText et = new TextInputEditText(MainActivity.this);
            et.setHint("Enter Member + 1");
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layout.addView(et,lp);
        }
    });
```

For example, I want the hint to increase the number to "Enter Number + X" each time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LinearLayout`'s `getChildCount` api, the demo code could be:

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.holder);
    TextInputEditText et = new TextInputEditText(this);
    int childNum = layout.getChildCount();
    et.setHint(String.format("Enter Member + %d", childNum+1));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.addView(et,lp);
```